# Getting : Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a gym application

Following Entities
ClientEntity

[image]

TrainerEntity

[image]

clientController

[image]

trainerController

[image]

ClientApi

[image]

trainer Api
[image]

I have created a bi directional mapping b/w trainer Entity and client entity

When I do findall for client or trainer I an getting nested json as in the Client api and is same with trainer api and is giving JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError);

Here I want from
client api

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bharath",
        "address": "#34324 Address",
        "trainerEntity": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Niranjan",
         }
    }
]
```

trainer api:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Niranjan",
        "clientEntity": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bharath",
            "address": "#34324 Address"
         }
     }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @JsonIgnoreProperties , there is a similar question already asked [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)
You can use
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ="clientEntity" )
Private TrainerEntity trainerEntity
and similarly for the the other side too

A better option is to use Dto's instead of entities to send the response as json.